# When calling props in bottomTabNavigator it is giving me error

Tags: react-native, redux

Can anyone help me out im a newbie in react-native and i have searched whole net and im not able to solve it

```
  Jobs: {
  screen:ACWebView ,
  params:{url:`${this.props.rootUrl}referrals`},
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <ACIcon name='briefcase'  style={[{color: tintColor, fontSize: 20}]} />

    ),
  },
},
```

here is my mapstatetoprops function

```
  function mapStateToProps(state) {
let currentInstitute = getCurrentInstitute(state);

return {
  navState: state.nav,
  rootUrl: currentInstitute.get('root_url')
};
```

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ACRouter);

> this is my jobs screen which will open a webview and i have to access props which contains the url what should i do